# Fuga de memoria al asignar punteros

Tags: c

He estado haciendo algunas pruebas con este código:

```
 int main()
 {
     int i;
     float *a, *b;


     a=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*10);

     b=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*20);

     b = a;  //FUGA DE MEMORIA??? 

     free(a); free(b); 
  }
```

Mi pregunta es, tal y como aparece en el comentario, ¿habrá una fuga de memoria al asignar el valor de "a" a "b", es decir ya no podré liberar esos 20 "floats" que reservé para "b"?

Y esa línea con dos llamadas a free(), ¿una de ellas es superflua (o incluso peligrosa)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿habrá una fuga de memoria al asignar el valor de "a" a "b", es decir ya no podré liberar esos 20 "floats" que reservé para "b"?

Correcto. En el momento en el que pierdas la referencia, el puntero, o como lo quieras llamar al bloque de memoria, ya no puedes acceder a el ... *ergo* tampoco lo puedes liberar.

> Y esa línea con dos llamadas a free(), ¿una de ellas es superflua (o incluso peligrosa)?

De *incluso peligrosa* nada. **Es un error**, e incurres en un comportamiento indefinido; puesto que ambas variables apuntan al mismo sitio, lo que estás haciendo en liberar ese bloque de memoria **2 veces**; tienes problemas **garantizado**.

Comment: Todo claro muchas gracias